# What's wrong with /timeline?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, timeline

For this question: [Is there a IE a:hover fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144401/is-there-a-ie-ahover-fix)

If you look at the Timeline: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6144401/timeline

Most of the timestamps are mere seconds apart.

Either this guy *really* can't make up his mind, or there's a bug.

[image]

The only reason I was looking is because I was confused where I'd lost 15 reputation from.

Comment: I'm guessing the guy is really confused.

Comment: I think what might have happened was that the guy repeatedly clicked on the checks on _all_ answers (for whatever reason) and the system only registered the first set of accept/unaccept attempts and forced delays.  Maybe he thought he was picking an answer at random and had to click the checks?

Comment: Maybe the guy knows what he's doing and is just trying to _freak you out_!

Comment: @Rick Sladkey: *It worked* :)

Comment: I added a comment to the question asking for the OPs input.

Comment: Can somebody tell me how I actually navigate to the timeline page? Other than directly typing it in, I mean

Comment: @JohnP By using this [super cool userscript](http://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-an), naturally (the timeline isn't linked from anywhere `bydesign`).

Comment: @Tim ahh it's one of those hush hush links! Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Either this guy *really* can't make up his mind, or there's a bug.

No bug, the timeline is correct.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/92858/timeline :)

Comment: We can has rate-limiting?